# Dynamically get all subscription ids under a given management group during ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-management-groups, azure-subscription

I would like to know during the template deployment all subscriptions that are under a specific Management Group.
I couldn't find any ARM template function that could get such info.

Is there a way to get this information?